# Catch scrapy signal ouside the spider

Tags: python, scrapy

In my spider I have a signal

```
    from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

    class PageSpider(CrawlSpider):

        def __init__(self):
            dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
            # some code

        def spider_closed(self, spider):
            #some code
            return 1
```

Is there a way to catch `spider_closed` signal outside the `PageSpider`? Or make some return from function?

Comment: What do you mean by _"outside the PageSpider"_? For example, you can write [an extension](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#sample-extension) listening on `spider_closed`. I don't understand _"make some return from function"_ either. Please explain your use-case more.

Comment: @paul trmbrth As you could see in my github question, I have a control script, which run more than one spider at once. The question is: how can I get the closed signal in another py-file? Should I use https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand _"how can I get the closed signal in another py-file"_. Have you looked at Scrapy extensions I linked earlier? You can also of course import any python module and call whatever code you need in the signal handler.

Comment: @paul trmbrth Maybe you can tell me, if I use `signals.connect(spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)`, can function **spider_closed** return something? I mean, when spider is closed, can it return something into variable?

Comment: Signals are to take actions, not to return values (to whom?). But you can take asynchronous actions, [`signal_closed`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed) can return a twisted deferred. And an action could be to write to some object somewhere